# How to return average of each condition in SQL

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook

I am struggling with this SQL question for several days. I am quite new to SQL. Really appreciate your time and effort.

**Q: returns the average arrival delay time for each day of the week.**

**Expect results**:

```
+--------------+---------------+
| weekday_name |   avg_delay   |
+--------------+---------------+
|    Friday    | 14.4520127056 |
|    Monday    | 10.5375015249 |
|   Thursday   | 8.47985564693 |
|  Wednesday   |  8.4561902339 |
|   Saturday   | 7.54455459234 |
|   Tuesday    | 4.63152453983 |
|    Sunday    | 4.21165978081 |
+--------------+---------------+
```

I already have two table ready: flight_delays and weekdayName
My sql code in ipython book:

```
SELECT distinct w.weekday_name, AVG(f.arr_delay) as average_delay
FROM flight_delays as f, weekdayName as w
WHERE f.day_of_week = w.dayofweek and w.dayofweek <= 7
ORDER BY AVG(arr_delay)
```

it only returns:

```
weekday_name    average_delay
Sunday          8.295147670495197
```

So it actually average all seven days' results. But I want to average results of each day. Could you please explain where is my mistake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: remove `distinct` and use `group by w.weekday_name`

Comment: In addition, any time you see a comma in your WHERE clause you're doing something wrong. Use a proper JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, learn to use proper `join` and `group by` syntax.  Also, I don't think `and w.dayofweek <= 7` is needed.

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT w.weekday_name, AVG(f.arr_delay) as average_delay
FROM flight_delays f join
     weekdayName w
     on f.day_of_week = w.dayofweek 
GROUP BY w.weekday_name
ORDER BY AVG(arr_delay)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Made some adjustments:

```
SELECT w.weekday_name, AVG(f.arr_delay) as average_delay
FROM flight_delays f INNER JOIN weekdayName w
ON f.day_of_week = w.dayofweek
GROUP BY w.weekday_name
ORDER BY AVG(arr_delay);
```

If you are doing aggregation(here `AVG`) in your `SELECT`, you need to provide non-aggregation fields in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my questions.

Comment: I wasn't sure earlier whether you wanted `w.dayofweek <= 7` in your condition which is why I kept it as it was. Edited and removed it if it helps.